# PHP fwrite vs. output piping

Tags: php, linux, file-io

I'm writing a tool that allows someone to connect to a web page and generate files for download on the fly.

To write these files, I can use PHP functions like fopen or fwrite, or I could create a script that can be called as a system call to generate the output such as:

php downloadGen.php > filetocreate.xml

The fwrite version of the solution uses more memory and is also slower than the piped version. Does anyone see any problems with executing the download generation as a system call? Would there be a cap on how many calls I could be running simultaneously?

Anyway, I'm hoping someone has experience with something similar and can offer some advice...

Answer (score 1):

> The fwrite version of the solution
>   uses more memory and is also slower
>   than the piped version

Are you sure?  I'll bet dollars to donuts it's the opposite (but in a negligible sort of way), and you're just measuring wrong.

Memory -

Building the file in-process via fopen/fwrite should consume less memory than creating a separate process on the server.  Perhaps you think it's the other way around because you're measuring how much memory your script is consuming.  But that `php downloadGen.xml` system call is starting up another process.  The PHP code there will use as much memory as it would if you did it in your webserver-bound process, plus all the overhead of cli php process.  So the difference should be negligible.

"Speed" -

The same applies to speed.  Starting up the PHP interpreter consumes processor cycles.  If you're doing this all synchronously, putting your generation/output code in the main script should be faster.  But only barely.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most efficient way (available since PHP 5.0) is to simply use file_put_contents() to insert the contents into the file. You specify the filename as the first parameter, and the string (either binary or simple text - it's a binary-safe function) of data to input into the file.

It will then generate the file at the path that you specify.

And to answer your second point, unless you have:

1. A HUGE number of users,
2. You are writing HUGE files constantly, or
3. Your server is crap

Then you'll be fine.

Comment: the problem with using file_put_contents is that I would have to store up the entire output in a variable prior out dumping it to the file.